# iOS Swift capture network packets

Tags: ios, networking, packet-capture

For a testing App i need to get network information from iOS. In Android there are API's available to obtain packets sent, received, size of them in bytes, and some other information. Is there anything similar in Apple iOS?

More deep information obtained with pcap C library can be used without Jailbreak?

Comment: Use the instruments panel, Instruments > Network. Another option would be to use [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com/) but this needs additional setup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> More deep information obtained with pcap C library can be used without Jailbreak?

Not by running a libpcap-based program on iOS, because Darwin, by default, makes the BPF devices openable only by root, so, on {OS X, iOS, tvOS} only a process running with root privileges can use libpcap to capture network traffic; without jailbreaking, you can't run a program as root on iOS (or tvOS).

However, with iOS 5 or later, you can use the [remote virtual interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1176/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10001707-CH1-SECIOSPACKETTRACING) facility in iOS and OS X to let a program running on a Mac see the traffic received and sent by an iOS machine.